# Root not filling whole partition and Home shrink error

Tags: dual-boot, partitioning

I have some problems, but first, let me describe my partition.

I am using a dual boot installation of Windows 10 and Ubuntu 20.04 LTS.
On Ubuntu, I split into 3 partitions:

- Root (/dev/sda6)
- Home (/dev/sda8)
- Swap (/dev/sda7)

[image: partition gparted]

So like the image above, my root (/dev/sda6) has a size of 57.59 GiB but only used about 34.20 GiB (Used) + 7.18 GiB (Unused) = 41.38 GiB. So, it looks like my root doesn't fill the whole partition, just look at the white areas don't cover the gray areas.

The second problem is, my home (/dev/sda8) seems too big, I want to move some GiB to my root (/dev/sda6). But, when I try to shrink it, it shows an error like this.

[image]

Just for your information, before this condition, I have done some partition operations using GParted. like moving home (/dev/sda8) to far-right, increasing swap space, and trying to increase root to 57.59 GiB (previously it was 41.38 GiB).

Comment: You can't move "home" to your "root" because your "swap" is in the way.  The space has to be continuous.  You would need to delete your swap (temporarily) before you can make such a move.  Something else you might want to consider is to use a [swapfile](https://linuxize.com/post/how-to-add-swap-space-on-ubuntu-20-04/) and remove the swap space altogether.  So, create the swapfile, switch to using the swapfile, then delete the swap partition.  Then move your "home" to your "root".

Comment: As for the space discrepancy of your root...that does look strange.  I don't know...  Perhaps you can do a file system check on root?  You might need to run Ubuntu off a USB drive since you will need to unmount root.  I'd fix this before the swap issue in my previous comment.

Comment: Oh sorry, I wanted to confirm, I don't know why, but after a few minutes (I did something else), and tried again, now it works. I'm a little confused, but I'm glad it worked. Thank you for your desire to help.

For information, yes, I have booted Ubuntu with USB. and also tried to do a Check on root (/dev/sda6), which 'previously' failed.

Comment: Oh, ok!  Nevertheless, try doing a `fsck.ext4` on your file systems and I do suggest you remove the swap partition.  Of course, keeping it is fine but I personally use a swapfile since I find it "gets in the way" when I'm resizing or moving partitions.

Answer (score 0):

I would remove the `SWAP-partition` (like Ray suggested) and use a `SWAP-file`, so you can use that space to extend your `/ partition` (root partition on which your OS is located). If you have 16 GB of RAM you probably don't need that much SWAP. 
If you want to make your `/home-partition` smaller, it will be done on its right side. Then you can move that partition to the right. That might take a while because it hat to copy the data. So making more free space on the left, which you can add to your `/ (root)-partition` ( when deleted the `SWAP-partition`. If I use a `SWAP-partition`, I always put it at the end of the disk, so it will never be in the way.
Use your USB-stick with your `Live Ubuntu` for these actions. And look at the link Ray provided.